GraphQL Schema Error: Missing query Operation
I'm working on Spring boot GraphQL project and im encountering an error while defining my GraphQL schema. It states:
Caused by: graphql.schema.idl.errors.SchemaProblem: errors=[A schema MUST have a 'query' operation defined]

I'm trying to create a schema with mutations (and potentially subscriptions) but don't currently require data retrieval functionalities. However, I understand the importance of a valid schema.
Can someone explain why the query operation is mandatory, even for mutation-only APIs?
Additionally, what are the recommended approaches for handling this scenario?
FYI, Here's a snippet of my relevant schema code :
type Mutation {
 sendMessage(message: String!, routingKey: String!): String!
 sendMessageWithDTO(msgDTO: MsgDTOInput!, routingKey: String!): String!
 sendMessageWithTTL(msgDTO: MsgDTOInput!, routingKey: String!, expire: Int!): String!
 sendToNormalExchange(msgDTO: MsgDTOInput!, routingKey: String!): String!
 sendWithDelay(msgDTO: MsgDTOInput!, routingKey: String!, delay: Int!): String!
}

input MsgDTOInput {
  message: String!
}


Query type is always required. Refer the spec document:


The query root operation type must be provided and must be an Object type.
The mutation root operation type is optional; if it is not provided, the service does not support mutations.
Similarly, the subscription root operation type is also optional; if it is not provided, the service does not support subscriptions.


For the reasons, GraphQL's creator has an explanation here

GraphQL's strength is in allowing you to request data in a specific
shape and evolve an API over time without breaking existing queries.
Mutations in GraphQL are valuable, but primarily because they offer an
API of write-then-read which lets you follow a mutation with a
specific query in the same atomic request.
For services that are write-only or have fire-and-forget mutations,
you're really not leveraging GraphQL's strengths and so you're
"paying" for an abstraction that you're not gaining from.

To fix this issue, a simple way is to add a dummy Query
type Query {
  dummy: String
}

